# Alxsx gem Package#to_stream fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axlsx

The ultimate goal here is to create a stream so that I can attach the xlsx doc generated from the axlsx package object. I'm able to serialize the package and it writes to the file system just fine.  I don't really have the need or want to write the document the file system.

Here is the error I get when I call `to_stream`:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `reopen' for "streamed":String Did
>   you mean? prepend

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Axlsx::Package.new do |p|
  p.workbook do |wb|
    wb.add_worksheet(name: 'Time Cards') do |ws|
      title_style = ws.styles.add_style(sz: 24)
      ws.add_row ["Week #{week}, #{year} Time Cards", '', ''], style: [title_style], height: 30
    end
  end
  p.to_stream
end
```

- Ruby v 2.4.0
- Rails v5.0.2

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors of this old question:

Check versions of `axlsx` and `rubyzip` in your Gemfile. For me the issue was that `rubyzip` was of version `1.2`. Combination that works for me today (07.08.2017) is:

`axlsx (2.1.0.pre)` and `rubyzip (~> 1.1.7)`